# How can I add loader state to firebase's createUserWithEmailAndPassword method?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I want to set a loader to my button while I call `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` using email & password. How can I do that?

For example in Apollo Client GraphQL, there is a loading state provided out of the box like:

```
const {data, loading, error} = <API call>
```

The given loading state automatically sets to true if the data fetching is in the works.

Is there any similar such way we can do it in firebase?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a built in function that's tied in with react state, so you would create the states yourself:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [error, setError] = useState(null);

// Whatever function is going to do the loading:
const onClick = async () => {
  try {
    setLoading(true);
    const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  } catch (error) {
    setError(error);
  } finally {
    setLoading(false);
  }
}
```